# error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory

Tags: python, git, ssh

I am running into an issue when trying to do a git push on a Popen() function where I get an ssh error

```
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

I believe this error is due to the fact that ssh is not in my python scripts path? If that is the case what would be the best way for me to handle this?

Here is my function call in case it would help

```
subprocess.Popen( 'git push', shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
```

also as an aside. git status works great so I know the git commands are working. it just chokes when it goes to interact with the server.

Comment: mac osx but hopefully there is a platform agnostic way to solve it

Comment: This may help you: http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/6/18/2159464

Comment: Have you considered using a package for interaction with Git? A quick search on PyPy suggests there's Gitlib, GitPython, GitPy and PyGit to choose from. I've not tried any of them, but it might save you some time.

Comment: @Thomas I did consider it but cannot use those packages for this application

Comment: @gorus close but not what i'm looking for. i need a solution that doesn't rely on the user to alter their ssh path. i'm not a python dev by any means but it seems to me that there should be an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: You need to retag this. Reading through, I though this was as issue when calling `git`. I suggest you at least add a `git` tag to warn the unwary.

Comment: Can you run the server-interacting git commands successfully "by hand" (directly from the command line)?

Comment: Can you successfully call `subprocess.Popen('ssh')`, or does that fail with the same error?

Comment: Have you tried using the env= parameter of subprocess.Popen to specify a PATH environment variable that contains your ssh executable?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the output of

```
subprocess.Popen("echo $PATH",shell=True)
```

it should contain the path of your ssh executable (also to be found in os.environ["PATH"]).
It is not the same as your python search path which is in sys.path

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed `ssh-client` installed This solve the problem on docker machines, even when ssh keys are present:

```
apt-get install ssh-client
```